# Was Ricky's mother complicit in Colonel Fitts' racism?

Tags: character, american-beauty

In *American Beauty* (1999), Ricky shows Jane his father's secret cache of Nazi memorabilia.  This gives us insight to his father's character as being racist.

Ricky's mother seems to be a caring woman, fighting a losing battle to raise their son in a nurturing home.  Her will seems overpowered by Colonel Frank.  Is it likely that she aware of Frank's memorabilia, and more importantly, can we know if she is given to similar feelings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing to indicate she feels the same way.  However, it's not uncommon to see a spouse "overlook" negative traits of their partner, particularly if the head of the household is abusive.  *Especially* if they are abusive, in fact.  Much like an abused spouse remains in the relationship even though they are beaten or ridiculed.  That was just the mindset of Ricky's mother.